# Read from Text file and write it into XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I want to Read a Text file and write it on to an existing XML file.

Text File format is

```
01 John
02 Rachel
03 Parker
```

And i want the Output on XML file as:

```
<StudentID>01<StudentID>
<StudentName>John<StudentName>
<StudentID>02<StudentID>
<StudentName>Rachel<StudentName>
<StudentID>03<StudentID>
<StudentName>Parker<StudentName>
```

Comment: Note that the output is not 'valid' xml as it has multiple root nodes. Therefore serialization is no option.

Comment: @MauriceStam false, serializing an IEnumerable<T> will give you multiple roots.

Comment: @Gusdor will this not result in an rootnote representing the collection type? If not, thanks for telling me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another quick way, if you need:

Having class Student as

```
class Student
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then following code should work:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\A.txt");
List<Student> list = new List<Student>();

foreach (string line in lines)
{
    string[] contents = line.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
    var student = new Student { ID = contents[0], Name = contents[1] };
    list.Add(student);
}  

using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\B.xml", FileMode.Create))
{
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Student>)).Serialize(fs, list);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is more than one way to do this, but I have a code snippet from an old project that will get you started. I changed it a bit to help.

```
    public void ReadtxtFile()
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        List<string> IdList = new List<string>;
        List<string> NameList = new List<string>;

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\Users\\Person\\Desktop";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(openFileDialog1.OpenFile()))
                    {
                        string line;
                        // Read and display lines from the file until the end of  
                        // the file is reached. 
                        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            tbResults.Text = tbResults.Text + line + Environment.NewLine;
                            int SpaceIndex = line.IndexOf("");
                            string Id = line.Substring(0, SpaceIndex);
                            string Name = line.Substring(SpaceIndex + 1, line.Length - SpaceIndex);
                           IdList.Add(Id);
                            NameList.Add(Name);
                        }
                       WriteXmlDocument(IdList, NameList);
                    }
                    myStream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void WriteXmlDocument(List<string> IdList, List<string> NameList)
        {
//Do XML Writing here
            }
        }
```